# Flutter: Implementing screen sharing in twilio-programmable-video

Tags: flutter, twilio

I am creating a screen mirror application in flutter using package: **twilio-programmable-video**. While connecting to room I want video track to be the device's screen as in webrtc we use getdisplayMedia(). *The problem is that **twilio-programmable-video** supports only camera source.* I tried to type cast MediaStreamTrack to VideoCapturer but the error **'MediaStreamTrack native is not a subtype of type 'Video Capturer in type cast'** occurs.

I tried to typecast MediaStreamTrack to VideoCapturer

```
const options = {'video': true, 'audio': true};

var captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(options);

LocalVideoTrack temp = LocalVideoTrack(true, captureStream.getTracks()[0] as VideoCapturer);
```